# Images of RateIt jquery plugin is not loaded in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

```
    <div class="rateit">
</div>
```

According to website http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm#ex_7a this should show the star symbol but this not happening in my case.I have included the javascript and CSS. I have kept the whole plugin in the new folder .How should I arrange the files of plugin  where should i keep the image in asp.net so that this will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Known i think you have to use like below

```
class="rateit bigstars"
```

You missed the bigstars.. i believe. 
Hope this helps...